# How can I solve this Firefox issue with url() such that it won't break in other browsers?

Tags: css, url, firefox, svg

I am rendering a chart with D3 that animates over time, showing links entering and exiting according to flow through a system.

In my chart, I have markers rendered on my links using marker-mid, to indicate direction of flow (see my [prototype pen](https://codepen.io/goodforenergy/pen/PZwqJj) for an idea of the markers). The links are entered using:

```
enteringLinks.append('polyline')
    .attr({
        'stroke-width': 0,
        style: 'marker-mid: url(#chevron);',
        stroke: 'transparent',
        path: function(d) {...},
        markers: function() {...},
        points: function() {...}
    });
```

The chevron is also setup programmatically earlier on:

```
svg.append('marker')
    .attr({
        id: 'chevron',
        // ...
    })
    .append('path')
    .attr({...});
```

I came across a strange bug in Firefox. After updating the query parameters on the page (using the history API), all new links are missing their markers. It appears after changing the URL, it can't find '#chevron'. Links already rendered on the page are not affected.

Although I can't understand this, I do know how to solve it for Firefox - prepend document.location.href to the marker url, to make `url(document.location.href + #chevron)`. I don't really understand why this works - why does it work on first load but not after a change? But more problematic is that this breaks all markers in IE9.

Aside from UA sniffing, I'd love advice on how I might solve this problem in Firefox without affecting other browsers.

Incidentally, I originally tried specifying marker-mid in an external stylesheet, but using that markers wouldn't appear in Firefox at all - same or related issue, I guess. My browser support requirements are all major browsers latest versions and IE9+.

Comment: If you use an external stylesheet the url must contain the name of the html/svg file that contains the marker. Did you do that?

Comment: Hi Robert - unfortunately this isn't an option for me - the markup is constructed through JS and exposed as an api + stylesheet that will be consumed by other parts of our product of which my code has no knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an inconsistency between the svg, css and html5 specifications how to handle the document URI changing via pushState and resources from fragment identifiers, which in turn leads to browsers implementing things differently.

- [mozilla bug 652991](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=652991)
- [old whatwg discussion](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-whatwg-archive/2011Apr/0235.html)
- [newer CSSWG discussion](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2016Mar/thread.html#msg298)

One suggested workaround seems to be to set `document.base` after pushstate.

Comment: Wow, thanks for these! I struggled to find relevant issues when I was searching. It looks like the Firefox issue is being worked on at the moment, so I'll wait to see what happens. I did try setting base after pushstate, but to no avail.